# Syntax error in Django template

Tags: django

I'm getting `Invalid block tag: 'else'`

The code is rather simple:

```
<tr>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
{% ifequal var1 "string" %}
    {% for i in range5 %}
            {% with v.i as an %}
        {% if an %}
            <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#A8A8A8">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#A8A8A8">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
ERROR HERE --> {% else %}
                    {% for i in range5 %}
            {% with .. %}
            {% if .. %}
            <tr>
        <td>></td>
            </tr>
            {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#A8A8A8">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endifequal %}
```

Comment: I dont see {% endifequal %}

Comment: @user710907 this is omitted - after the {% else %}

Answer (score 1):

And `else` tag must be within an `if` tag in django templates. The last `else` tag does not fall into any `if` tag since you ended the `if` statement with `endif`.

Comment: Can't I use `else` within `ifequal` ?

Comment: @ftkg: Yes you most certainly can.

Comment: Well, there's a `ifequal` tag open, so `else` should be eligible?

Comment: `{% ifequal %}` can have an `else` followed by `{% endifequal %}` In your case, you have a dangling `{% else %}` which is invalid. Just put an `{% endifequal  %}` after the `{% else %}` to see what i mean.

Comment: @karthikr @ftkg, its as he says, all that matters is the `endif`.

Comment: @karthikr I had omitted the rest of the code. There is indeed a `endifequal`

Comment: The code you have shown us is fine. I am pretty sure you are omitting something from the original code which is causing the issue. Check the [indented code](http://jsfiddle.net/8zT77/) which is perfectly fine